# Xfce: restart xfce without logging out with new display configuration

Tags: ubuntu, archlinux, xserver, xfce, xrandr

I have a problem with the support of my dual screen after a suspend. I set up my laptop with xrandr to use only an external screen with the laptop screen off. Then I did a suspend. Then back to home with no external screen when I wake up my laptop I get of course a blank screen for my laptop screen.

How to set up the display to use the laptop screen without logging out from my xfce session?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- get a tty `ctrl + alt + F1`
- log you
- in the shell `export DISPLAY=:0`
- then, type your `xrandr` command to set the output to your laptop
- finaly, retrieve your GUI with `ctrl + alt + F7`

May it works.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet for those who may have the same question: Use arandr to set your monitors up. Save the settings (creates a shell script for you in `~/.screenlayout/` ) then assign a shortcut key to it.  You can have multiple scripts there so you could have multiple configs, and change them with different keystrokes. Then when you wake up your laptop, press the keystroke, and it should execute the script. or add the export DISPLAY line from the above answer at the beginning of the script, and run the script (`~/.screenlayout/scriptname.sh`) The one caveat with the DISPLAY= method is that you may have to set in your xfce startup another script that runs: xhost +   to allow connections from other terminals. Not secure to do this, but if you're on your own private network and relatively certain there is no one else on it, then it could be "OK" to do that.